# VirtualPathUtility.IsAbsolute(path) throws exception when path contains parameters

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, exception

Why is it that in ASP.NET

`VirtualPathUtility.IsAbsolute("/~abc")` works fine.

but `VirtualPathUtility.IsAbsolute("/~abc?n=1)` throws exception:

> System.Web.HttpException: '~/abc?n=1' is not a valid virtual path?

**UPDATE**:

I've just checked that there's a difference in behaviour between .NET 3.5 and .NET 4.0. `VirtualPathUtility.IsAbsolute("/~abc?n=1)` works fine in 4.0 but not in 3.5. Do any of you know why they've changed that?

Answer (score 5):

Because `/~abc?n=1` is not a path, it includes the querystring part of the URL too (`/~abc` is the path, `n=1` is the query string)

Comment: I've noticed that there's difference in how .NET 3.5 and 4.0 handle that situation.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to pass is url with query params, not path. Use path. Btw IsAbsolute returns true if the string starts with "/" character, so you don't need to use the method - just check it on your own.